# Error in ansible 2.3.2- Unsupported proxy scheme: https

Tags: ansible-2.x

I am getting error:

```
 Unsupported proxy scheme: https. Currently ansible only supports HTTP proxies
```

while running ansible playbook on ansible v2.3.2 but same is running with ansible v1.9.4:

```
environment:
  http_proxy: "http://{{ address }}:{{ port }}"
  https_proxy: "https://{{ address }}:{{ port }}"
```

Is there any change in ansible module or how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is present also in `ansible 2.7.1`

to avoid this problem you can set `validate_certs: false`

here is an example:

```
environment:
  http_proxy: http://IP:PORT
  https_proxy: https://IP:PORT
```

and in your get_url or apt task you add `validate_certs: false`

```
get_url:
      url: url
      dest: "{{ dest }}"
      validate_certs: false
```

Comment: Set `validate_certs` as false saved my life, thanks. Would you mind explaining why to add `validate_certs: false` ?

Answer (score 2):

I troubleshooted and found if we set HTTPS_PROXY in place of http_proxy, strange but its working and package is installing.

```
 HTTPS_PROXY: "https://{{ address }}:{{ port }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confirming that adding `validate_certs: false` do the trick:

```
get_url:
  url: url
  dest: "{{ dest }}"
  validate_certs: false
```

And following DOESN'T WORK: `HTTPS_PROXY: "https://{{ address }}:{{ port }}"`